# Schedule in Laravel not work on host server

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel, schedule

I have a schedule function in Laravel. It work good on localhost but it doesn't work on host server.

Hi,
I want send SMS for some customers daily. I wrote schedule in Laravel. It works good in localhost using :
`php artisan schedule:run`

my schedule function :

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     */
    protected $commands = [            
        Commands\MyCommands::class
    ];
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            $hc = new SendSMSController();
            $hc->sendDelaySMS();
          })->everyMinute();
    }
```

and my CPanel cronjob is:
`*  11  *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/boschapp/domains/warranty.boschapp.ir/public_html/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

But it doesn't work on host server.

Comment: Try edit php version with /usr/local/bin/php and than use the absolute path e.g.

*  11  *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/ea-php82 /home/boschapp/domains/warranty.boschapp.ir/public_html/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: Your cron `*  11  *   *   * ` means it runs `At every minute past hour 11.` (got this from cronguru). If your intention is to run it every minute, your cron should say `* * * * *`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give details of how _it doesn't work on host server._

Comment: Thank you dear @shaz3e . I used your solution and it works for me. really thank you so much